# CSharp skip file through loop if it contains some string

Tags: c#, file, loops, text, readline

Good morning,
I am looping through many text files in a folder to get the text written inside of them. 
The name of the file is automatically written by another progam in a standard like `date_filename.id`, so I cannot be able to filter the files basing on the file name...

I noticed that they have a file identification on the first line like `ORDERR` or `Something else` so I was thinking if there's some method to skip the file if the first line contains some string.The loop looks like this at the moment:

```
 DirectoryInfo FilesPath = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 var Files = FilesPath.GetFiles();
 foreach (var file in Files)
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
            {

                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (s.Contains("ORDERR"))
                    {
                        "Do something"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
```

But when the loop reach the second line, obviusly, it will skip the rest.
What can I do?

Thank you in advance for any kind of help

(I cannot be able to find something through stackoverflow)

Comment: Order error as a status could be ORD ERR without the space.

Comment: I dont get what the issue is here ...

Comment: Put break; the line after your "Do something".  That will jump out of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i really got your requirement. But isn't it simple as(using LINQ for readability):

```
var relevantFiles = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles()
   .Where(f => File.ReadLines(f.FullName).ElementAtOrDefault(0)?.Contains("ORDERR")==false);
```

Note that i use `EnumerateFiles` which is more efficient because it doesn't need to load all files into memory even if you want to skip them. The same applies to `File.ReadLines`(as opposed to `ReadAllLines`). `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault` returns `null` if the file is empty, that's why i used the null-conditional-operator `?`. So the query will skip files which first line contains `ORDERR`.

Comment: Seriously, that was the best answer... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a flag to set and break out of the readloop

```
DirectoryInfo FilesPath = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var Files = FilesPath.GetFiles();
foreach (var file in Files)
{
    bool hasError = false;
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
    {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (s.Contains("ORDERR"))
            {
                hasError = true;
                break;
             } else {
                lines.Add(s)
             }
        }
    }

    if (!hasError) 
    {
        // do something with lines as we were ok with it 
    }
}
```